# Trying to figure out how to check whether a potential array element is out of bounds

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the neighbors of a specific element (the number 0) that can be placed anywhere in a NxN 2D array. This wouldn't be an issue if the 0 were in the center, but if it's on the top/bottom rows, for example, it won't have a value above/below it, and the same with the far left/right and corner cases. It should be noted that I only need to check the values that are directly horizontal/vertical to it, not diagonal. Is there a specific method that can be called to determine whether a specific index even exists?

Answer (score 2):

You can derive that information from the length of the array.

Given a 2-dimensional array `array[m][n]` where you consider the first dimension to represent the rows, and the second dimension to represent the columns:

```
array[0][whatever] // top row
array[m-1][whatever] // bottom row
array[whatever][0] // left-most column
array[whatever][n-1] // right-most column
```

Applying this (formatted for readability):

```
Object current = array[i][j];

Object left =   j > 0       ? array[i][j-1] : null;
Object right =  j < (n - 1) ? array[i][j+1] : null;
Object top =    i > 0       ? array[i-1][j] : null;
Object bottom = i < (m - 1) ? array[i+1][j] : null;
```

In any case: don't solve this problem by catching `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It's considered bad form to catch runtime exceptions that can be 100% avoided.

Comment: Right, but what if [0][whatever] leads to an element that doesn't exist? Say, for example, if the element I'm trying to find neighbors for is on the far left, and I search for something to the left of it - something that doesn't exist. I'm basically just looking for a way to 'check' if it has those neighbors before I even do anything with them, so I don't get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Well, you know it's on the far left if the second index is `0`, so then you also know that you should not be looking for neighbors on the left. If you're addressing element `array[i][j]`, and `j` equals `0`, then don't search for something to the left of that element.

Answer (score 0):

eg  take a

```
[3][3] array
```

and `i and j` are for row and column indexes

just check

```
//horizontal
if(i - 1 >= N){ //N being 3
//do check for
}
if(i + 1 <= N){ // N being 3
//do check
}
//vertical
if(j - 1 >= N){ //N being 3
//do check for
}
if(j + 1 <= N){ // N being 3
//do check
}
```

though id prefer to just surround my entire operation ( of checking neighbors -1 and + 1 both horizontal and vertical) with a try catch

```
try{
//your checks for correct and incorrect indexes doesnt matter if it goes beyond.
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
// handle here let all other exceptions break your program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy using exception handling method.

```
 somefunction(int arr[10][10], int num ){
int i, j;
  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(j=0; j<10; j++){
      if(arr[i][j]==num)
        break;
    }
  }
//i is rows and j is columns
try{
  for(int k=-1 ; k<=1; k++){
    for(int l=-1 ; l<=1; l++){
      System.out.println(arr[i+k][j+l]);
    }
  }
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

}
}
```